# Decorating a method which will be inspected

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am writing a dispatch method. It takes in a dictionary which was parsed from JSON and uses the JSON fields as parameters in a function call. The idea behind this is that I want to be able to provide error messages to the sender, but I don't want to write out the code to check for the parameters for each method (there are dozens). So I used this method to simultaneously provide good error messages while reducing the amount of work I have to do.

However, I am now trying to wrap the called functions with a decorator. The decorator interferes with the inspection of the method, and I can't figure a way around it.

---

#### Further Detail

Here's a simplified version of the existing code. It works great! I get back useful error messages detailing which parameters were not supplied.

```
import inspect

class MyClass:
    # There is plenty of other code in here.
    ...

    # Here's the relevant part:
    def dispatch(self, json, action):
        try:
            func = self.DISPATCH[action]
            try:
                return func(self, **json)
            except TypeError:
                sig = inspect.signature(func)
                missing_fields = []
                for param in filter(lambda p: p.name != 'self' and p.kind == p.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD and p.default == p.empty, sig.parameters.values()):
                    if param.name not in json:
                        missing_fields.append(param.name)
                if missing_fields:
                    # Tell the sender which fields they were missing.
                    ...
                else:
                    # Check if the number of arguments was wrong.
                    # Send back a good error message if that's the problem,
                    # otherwise `raise`.
                    ...
        except KeyError:
            # The `action` was not in the `DISPATCH`.
            ...

    def method(self, foo, bar):
        # Do some stuff.
        ...

    DISPATCH = {
        'method': method,
    }
```

Now I'm trying to add this decorator to check if a user is logged-in before allowing the function call to occur:

```
def _check_login(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_is_logged_in:
            # Raise the appropriate error.
            ...
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I just stick `@_check_login` on the line ahead of `def method` in the larger code section. However, the `inspect.signature` call now looks at `wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)` instead of the actual function and constantly says that the wrong values were supplied. I understand this is how decorators work; I'm just looking for a workaround.

Comment: This is a solved problem.  You want [`decorator`](http://pythonhosted.org/decorator/documentation.html).

Comment: Use the `@wraps` decorator: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: @KlausD.: That's better than nothing, but it doesn't solve OP's problem because that only copies over some of the dunder values and not the signature.

Comment: @Kevin wow, I've been using decorators for a while and yet somehow I've never heard of this module! Post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks so much anyway, but Kevin's right that I needed the signature intact.

Comment: You should perhaps have a read of http://blog.dscpl.com.au/p/decorators-and-monkey-patching.html and consider using the ``wrapt`` package to implemented decorators. The use of ``@wraps`` doesn't solve all the problems that can arise.